# Spacing in table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I've a problem with my table of contents in LaTeX.
For some reason it uses the entire page area. The 
problem is illustrated here:

http://twpmedia.se/kilten/files/tableofcontent.pdf

Anyone knows a solution to this, so that the second
content page uses the same spacing as the first?

Maybe I should point out that I'm using

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It looks like you're using a KoMaScript class (`scrbook`, perhaps), which has its own method for setting the parskip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem with the second page of toc getting stretched out over the page. What solved it for me was simply adding `\newpage`:

```
\tableofcontents

\newpage
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you had some `\pagebreak` command after `\tableofcontents`? That would explain the behavior with the `scrbook` class. If you need to force a page break because you have something like a dedication page, use `\cleardoublepage`.

It looks like you're using the `scrbook` class for your document. In this case you shouldn't use the `parskip` package, but add to the class the corresponding option. Typesetting this mock document doesn't show your problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{flushright}
Dedicated to my cat
\end{flushright}
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The same (without `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`) if you're using `scrreprt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In documents with the layout "twoside" (like yours) KOMAscript uses \flushbottom. Maybe you can try:

```
{% Begin a group
\raggedbottom%
\tableofcontents
}%end of the group
```

But that's just a long shot in the dark, maybe you should provide your preamble here.